# Creating a velocity of 45 mph

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, acceleration

For a project, I want to record different G values in deceleration (around the range of 40Gs).

But to attain that amount of deceleration, I know I need to attain about 35 to 45 mph.

My object is on a linear bearing with sensors.

I wanted to know how to get to that speed of 35 to 45 mph.

Any ideas?
I thought springs would do but that doesn't even remotely get me to that speed.

Comment: How long A track can you build

Comment: This is a question about engineering, not physics.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A.  is to just drop it vertically,  simple but I don't know your setup. There must be some reason you can't do this.

Plan B is horizontal but could be combined  with Plan A

Copy the Wright brothers. Build a track with a weight pulled by a wire dropping downwards. As if the track is a table top with a pulley at the end and the weight dropping down.

The weight is connected to the object by a  wire, The g is very high so you need a long drop, or a boost using springs  at the start and you counter the increase in velocity over time by dampening the falling weight with progressive spring strengths to keep acceleration under control.

When you want the decleration to begin, cut the wire or put a block below the weights to stop their descent.

That is what the Wright's  did,  except they built a tower and hoisted the weight to the top.

Its  a simple  version of a carrier steam catapult aircraft launch system.

Gravity is free, and easy to manipulate. Linear drives and associated motors and electronics are not.

Answer (score -1):

You may wish to look at something like http://www.e-fliterc.com/Products/Default.aspx?ProdID=EFLDF32#quickSpecs (Delta-V (R) 32 80mm EDF Unit electric motor with a fan - about $40). It provides 5.40 lb static thrust and 1400 W power at 22 V. If your object's mass is, say, about 0.2 lb (about 90 gram), the motor may provide about 10 g acceleration (the motor mass is 116 gram). Thus, you can boost your object to 45 mph (about 20 m/s) in about 0.2 s over a distance of about 2 m. You may use a shorter ring track (preferably so that the thrust would not pull the object from the track).